reset draggable items to original position
I need a button  to reset draggable items position to original to the following fiddle.
fiddle here  https://jsfiddle.net/adgram/714w6x3t/20/


$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.event').on("dragstart", function(event) {
    var dt = event.originalEvent.dataTransfer;
    dt.setData('Text', $(this).attr('id'));
  });
  $('table td').on("dragenter dragover drop", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (event.type === 'drop') {
      var data = event.originalEvent.dataTransfer.getData('Text', $(this).attr('id'));
      if ($(this).find('span').length === 0) {
        de = $('#' + data).detach();
        de.appendTo($(this));
        //alert("ok"); //mine 
        document.getElementById("done").innerHTML = data + " moved!";
      }

    };
  });
})
table th,
table td {
  height: 30px;
  width: 200px;
}

table span {
  display: block;
  background-color: #09C;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title></title>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow">
  <meta name="googlebot" content="noindex, nofollow">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.1.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <div id="done" style=" text-align: center;color:red;"></div>
    <table id="#our_table" border="1">
      <tr>
        <th>Jun 1</th>
        <th>Jun 2</th>
        <th>Jun 3</th>
        <th>Jun 4</th>
        <th>Jun 5</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><span class="event" id="a" draggable="true">aaa</span></td>
        <td><span class="event" id="b" draggable="true">bbb</span></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><span class="event" id="c" draggable="true">ccc</span></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><span class="event" id="d" draggable="true">dddd</span></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><span class="event" id="e" draggable="true">eeee</span></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td><span class="event" id="f" draggable="true">ffff</span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><span class="event" id="g" draggable="true">gggg</span></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td><span class="event" id="h" draggable="true">hhhh</span></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>




    </table>

  </div>
  <input class="resetall" type="submit" id="reset" value="reset">
  original https://jsfiddle.net/videma/2RuBh/



</body>

</html>



fiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/adgram/714w6x3t/20/
When draggable is true the cell can move. I tried if the draggable should revert but not works.if
someone can help, I dont need all the items to reset. Because my programm when I make the first drop it runs code , I need only the first move to reset

I had a try with getBoundingClientRect();
I don't think as it is right , also after reset, the span not moving any more.
Please have a look https://jsfiddle.net/adgram/714w6x3t/106/

I´d say you need to store the history, or in your case the initial positions, for each draggable then, because on the initial position of the one you want to reset, could already be another draggable which you would to reset as well then?

When you drag and drop, you don't change the position, but the structure of the html. So save the html and restore it itself. Something like this:


$(document).ready(function () {
  const originTable = $('#our_table').html();
  $(document).on('dragstart', '.event', function (event) {
    var dt = event.originalEvent.dataTransfer;
    dt.setData('Text', $(this).attr('id'));
  });
  $(document).on('dragenter dragover drop', '#our_table td', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (event.type === 'drop') {
      var data = event.originalEvent.dataTransfer.getData(
        'Text',
        $(this).attr('id'),
      );
      if ($(this).find('span').length === 0) {
        de = $('#' + data).detach();
        de.appendTo($(this));
        //alert("ok"); //mine
        document.getElementById('done').innerHTML = data + ' moved!';
      }
    }
  });

  $(document).on('click', '.restore', function () {
    $('#our_table').html(originTable);
  });
});
table th,
table td {
  height: 30px;
  width: 200px;
  border: solid 1px;
}
table span {
  display:block;
  background-color: #09C;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="restore">Restore</button>
<div
  id="done"
  style="text-align: center; color: red"
></div>
<table
  id="our_table"
>
  <tr>
    <th>Jun 1</th>
    <th>Jun 2</th>
    <th>Jun 3</th>
    <th>Jun 4</th>
    <th>Jun 5</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <span
        class="event"
        id="a"
        draggable="true"
        >aaa</span
      >
    </td>
    <td>
      <span
        class="event"
        id="b"
        draggable="true"
        >bbb</span
      >
    </td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <span
        class="event"
        id="c"
        draggable="true"
        >ccc</span
      >
    </td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <span
        class="event"
        id="d"
        draggable="true"
        >dddd</span
      >
    </td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <span
        class="event"
        id="e"
        draggable="true"
        >eeee</span
      >
    </td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td>
      <span
        class="event"
        id="f"
        draggable="true"
        >ffff</span
      >
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <span
        class="event"
        id="g"
        draggable="true"
        >gggg</span
      >
    </td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td>
      <span
        class="event"
        id="h"
        draggable="true"
        >hhhh</span
      >
    </td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>



